# Read substring between two strings CF

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

In an HTML file, I need to extract the date string between two substrings.

Example string :

```
<A HREF="actuals_ADAPS_20150517_3.txt"></A> <A HREF="actuals_ADAPS_20150517_3.txt">actuals_ADAPS_20150517_3.t&gt;</A> May 17 00:50      4k <A HREF="actuals_ADAPS_20150518_1.txt"></A> <A HREF="actuals_ADAPS_20150518_1.txt">actuals_ADAPS_20150518_1.t&gt;</A> May 17 18:50      4k <A HREF="actuals_ADAPS_20150518_3.txt"></A> <A HREF="actuals_ADAPS_20150518_3.txt">actuals_ADAPS_20150518_3.t&gt;</A> May 18 00:50      4k
```

Example string represents 3 text files and their associated times.

I need to extract the times for each of these files.

I have gone through the REGEX route but haven't been able to get the correct one.

Code so far:

```
<cfdump var="#REMatch('actuals_METR_YOUNN_20150520_3.t&gt;(.*)4k',html)#">
```

The code is not right but gives an idea on where am I heading.

For filename :actuals_ADAPS_20150517_3.txt

Expected Output :
`May 17 00:50`

Current Output:

[image: Rematch Output]

Note: As per Leigh in the comments, ReMatch (unfortunately) returns the entire string matched, instead of just the grouped expression as you would expect.

I had to use the `REReplace` on top of `ReMatch` to get the desired output.

Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.. just make your `.*` greedy by adding `?`.. and exclude trailing space by adding `\s*` after it.

```
actuals_ADAPS_20150517_3\.t&gt;<\/A>\s*(.*?)\s*4k
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wF6bS8/3)

Comment: Thanks Karthik. Although the `actuals_ADAPS_20150517_3.t&gt;<\/A>\s(.*?)\s*4k` gives me the output I'm expecting on the DEMO site but its not working on Coldfusion. Not sure if there is something else I'm missing.

Comment: @GauravS ive checked the docs of [coldfusion](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a38f-7ffb.html) and the regex should work.. are you missing anything in your question?

Comment: @karthikmanchala Check your demo link. It is matching the closing anchor as well.

Comment: @GauravS - What do you mean by "not working"?  Please update your question with the code (and string value) used, as well as the results and how they differ from what you expected.

Comment: @Leigh : I'm not getting the expected output of `May 17 00:50`  when using the ReMatch function. The question already has the example string and code used. I'm getting an empty array in the results.

Comment: @GauravS - Can you put that in your question so it is more visible? Not everyone reads comments.

Comment: @Leigh : I have updated the question, there was a spelling mistake earlier hence was getting an empty array. Even now, the output is not correct as per the `DEMO` link.

Comment: I do not have an answer for you, but IIRC, ReMatch (unfortunately) returns the entire string matched, instead of just the grouped expression as you would expect.  Hence the results you are seeing. Not sure why they implemented it that way....

Comment: Ahh @Leigh : Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @karthikmanchala : Accepting the answer for helping me in getting the correct regex. Coldfusion has a strange way of matching the regex. Thanks.